# Using a synchronizedSet to synchronize access between two threads

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety, set

I'm not able to synchronize two threads using a set:

```
private Set<String> set;
...
set = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<String>());
```

and passing it to two threads. One accessing:

```
synchronized (set) {
    // [1]
    if (set.contains(str)) {
    ...
    } else {
        // [3]
    }
}
```

and another updating:

```
synchronized (set) {
    set.add(str);   // [2]
...
}
```

What happens is that [1], [2], [3] happens in sequence. During [1], it is correct that the set doesn't have yet the item I'm looking for. But then [2] updates it by adding the item. And during [3], I now see the item. How do I fix this? I also have a ConcurrentHashMap being shared by the same threads but it works perfectly fine. What is the set's equivalent to ConcurrentHashMAp?

UPDATE: The code is too long. Anyway, my updated question is - What is the set's equivalent to ConcurrentHAshMap?

Comment: 1->2->3 should not happen.  1->3 is mutually exclusive to 2.  That is when 1 is invoked, 2 should never be invoked until after 3 is invoked (if 3 is invoked).

Comment: Provide plz full code fragment. These synchronized blocks does not allow to run two or more threads concurrently neither set is not synchronized not set is thread-safe.

Comment: For debugging purposes, print out the identity of the set in each thread using http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode(java.lang.Object) to check whether they are both using the same synchronized wrapper...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are synchronizing access correctly. Actually, wrapping it in `synchronizedSet()` is not having any additional effect here. There is no `ConcurrentHashSet` though you can kind of get the same thing from `Collections.newSetFromMap()` and `ConcurrentHashMap`. But this isn't the problem.

The problem is somewhere else in your code. For example: are you sure you're synchronizing on the same set? are your keys implementing `hashCode()` and `equals()` correctly? have you made them mutable (bad idea) and something is changing the keys?

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to correct the accepted answer and note that `Collections.synchronizedSet(...)` does actually make a difference. Calling it creates a `SynchronizedSet` object (subclass of `SynchronizedCollection`) which wraps around the provided `Set` and uses a `mutex` object as a lock to synchronize access to the underlying `Set`.

With this in mind, the `Set` returned from `Collections.synchronizedSet(...)` does not need to be externally synchronized when being accessed - unless you are traversing it via `Iterator`, `Spliterator` or `Stream`. See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedSet(java.util.Set)).